# C - Unlink/Remove produces error for filenames with spaces

Tags: c, file-io, unlink

I am trying to make a function in C to erase all the contents of a temp folder and to erase the folder.
Whilst I already have successfully created the code to cycle through the files and to erase the folder  (it is pretty much straight forward) I am having trouble erasing the files using unlink.
Here is the code that I am using:

```
int delete_folder(char *foldername) {
 DIR *dp;
 struct dirent *ep;
 dp=opendir(foldername);
 if (dp!=NULL) {
      readdir(dp); readdir(dp);
      while (ep=readdir(dp)) {
           char* cell = concatenate(concatenate(foldername, "\\"), "Bayesian Estimation.xlsx");//ep->d_name);
           printf("%s\n", cell);
           remove(cell);
           printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));

      }
      closedir(dp);
 }
 if (!rmdir(foldername)) {return(0);} else {return(-1);}
}
```

The code that I wrote is fully functional for all files but those which include spaces in the filename. After some testing, I can guarantee that the unlink functions eliminates all files in the folder (even those with special characters in the filename) but fails if the filename includes a space (however, for this same file, if I remove the space(s), this function works again).

Has anyone else encountered this problem? And, more importantly, can it be solved/circunvented?
(The problem remains even if I introduce the space escape sequences directly)
The error presented by unlink is "No such file or directory" (ENOENT). Mind you that the file is indeed at the referred location (as can be verified by the code outputing the correct filename in the variable *cell*) and this error also occurs if I use the function remove instead of unlink.

PS: The function *concatenate* is a function of my own making which outputs the concatenation of the two input strings.

Edit:
The code was written in Codeblocks, in Windows.
Here's the code for the concatenate function:

```
char* concatenate(char *str1, char *str2) {
 int a1 = strlen(str1), a2 = strlen(str2); char* str3[a1+a2+1];
 snprintf(str3, a1+a2+2, "%s%s", str1, str2);
 return(str3);
}
```

Whilst you are right in saying that it is a possible (and easy) memory leak, the functions' inputs and outputs are code generated and only for personal use and therefore there is no great reason to worry about it (no real need for foolproofing the code.)

Comment: Does `concatenate` use `malloc()` to allocate th concatenated strings? How do they get `free()ed`?

Comment: @Barmar, that's obviously a test case, as evidenced by the fact the _actual_ rest-of-line is after the comment. In any case, _show_ us `concatenate()`, _we_ can't be sure it workds as advertised.

Comment: I can't think of any reason for this problem. `unlink` and `remove` don't parse the filename, except to find the `/` directory separators.

Comment: Print the output of `concatenate` and see if it is actually the correct path.

Comment: OP needs to supply more info. The use of backslash and Excel files seems to indicate Windows but I'm not sure it comes with all those nifty `opendir`-type functions. Are you doing this is CygWin or something similar?

Comment: Also, I'm slightly suspicious of what happens to `cell` after the scope ends -- is it reusing a shared memory buffer or is it returning a new one every time?

Comment: Which OS are you on? If linux then run the program under `truss` and have a look at which file it is actually trying to unlink

Comment: `char* cell = concatenate(concatenate(foldername, "\\")` is suspicious too. Either this is a memory leak or you've violated a re-entrancy constraint. Can you show the code for `concatenate` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for all your input, after reviewing your comments and making a few experiments myself, I figured out that remove/unlink was not working because the filename was only temporarily saved at variable *cell* (it was there long enough for it to be printed correctly to console, hence my confusion). After appropriately storing my filename before usage, my problem has been completely solved.
Here's the code (I have already checked it with filenames as complex as I could make them):

```
int delete_folder(char* foldername) {
 DIR *dp;
 struct dirent *ep;
 dp=opendir(foldername);
 if (dp!=NULL) {
      readdir(dp); readdir(dp);
      while (ep=readdir(dp)) {
           char cell[strlen(foldername)+1+strlen(ep->d_name)+1];
           strcpy(cell, concatenate(concatenate(foldername, "\\"), ep->d_name));
           unlink(cell);
           printf("File \"%s\": %s\n", ep->d_name, strerror(errno));
      }
      closedir(dp);
 }
 if (!rmdir(foldername)) {return(0);} else {return(-1);}
}
```

I realize it was kind of a noob mistake, resulting from my being a bit out of practice for a while in programming in C, so... Thank you very much for your all your help!

Answer (score 1):

You say "using `unlink()`" but the code is using `remove()`.  Which platform are you on?  Is there any danger that your platform implements `remove()` by running an external command which doesn't handle spaces in file names properly?  On most systems, that won't be a problem.

What is a problem is that you don't check the return value from `remove()` before printing the error.  You should only print the error if the function indicates that it generated an error.  No function in the Standard C (or POSIX) library sets `errno` to zero. Also, errors should be reported on standard error; that's what the standard error stream is for.

```
if (remove(cell) != 0)
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to remove %s (%d: %s)\n", cell, errno, strerror(errno));
else
    printf("%s removed OK\n", cell);
```

I regard the `else` clause as a temporary measure while you're getting the code working.

It also looks like you're leaking memory like a proverbial sieve.  You capture the result of a double concatenate operation in `cell`, but you never free it.  Indeed, if the nested calls both allocate memory, then you've got a leak even if you add `free(cell);` at the end of the loop (inside the loop, after the second `printf()`, the one I deconstructed).  If `concatenate()` doesn't allocate new memory each time (it returns a pointer to statically allocated memory, then I think concatenating a string with the output of `concatenate()` is also dangerous, probably invoking undefined behaviour as you copy a string over itself.  You need to look hard at the code for `concatenate()`, and/or present it for analyis.